# can i make relationship between nodes based on their array prop in Neo4j?

Tags: arrays, import, neo4j, nodes, relationship

If I have a csv file containing rows and each row forms a single node
Can I link nodes to each other and to themselves based on 2 properties where these properties are arrays?
So that each element of an array is associated with another element of the second array based on a specific arrangement from another csv file, and it forms the relationship between the two nodes or between the node and itself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work. Load the nodes from the first CSV first, and then load the relationships from the second CSV.

This documentation might help you.
https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

This tutorial might also be useful.
https://towardsdatascience.com/importing-csv-files-in-neo4j-f3553f1a76cf

I don't know if I am correctly understanding your use case, but here is some sample code.

Assume you have a CSV for nodes called node.csv with these values:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

You have a CSV for relationships with these values:

```
1,2,3,1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5,6
4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Start by creating a unique constraint for the node.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT item_uinque_key ON (i:Item) ASSERT i.idArray IS UNIQUE
```

Next, load the nodes. LOAD CSV assumes that all fields are strings, so we have to convert them to integers.

```
LOAD CSV from 'file:///nodes.csv' AS row
WITH [x in row | toInteger(x)] AS idArray
MERGE (i:Item {idArray:idArray})
RETURN i
```

Finally, load the relationships.

```
LOAD CSV from 'file:///relationships.csv' as row
WITH [x in row[..3] | toInteger(x)] AS sourceId, 
[x in row[3..] | toInteger(x)] AS targetId
MATCH (s:Item {idArray:sourceId}), (t:Item {idArray:targetId})
MERGE (s)-[:RELATES_TO]->(t)
RETURN *
```